# Force rsync to compare local files byte by byte instead of checksum

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, rsync

I have written a Bash script to backup a folder. At the core of the script is an `rsync` instruction

```
rsync -abh --checksum /path/to/source /path/to/target
```

I am using `--checksum` because I neither want to rely on file size nor modification time to determine if the file in the source path needs to be backed up. However, most -- if not all -- of the time I run this script locally, i.e., with an external USB drive attached which contains the backup destination folder; no backup over network. Thus, there is no need for a delta transfer since both files will be read and processed entirely by the same machine. Calculating the checksums even introduces a speed down in this case. It would be better if `rsync` would just `diff` the files if they are both on stored locally.

After reading the manpage I stumbled upon the `--whole-file` option which seems to avoid the costly checksum calculation. The manpage also states that this is the default if source and destination are local paths.

So I am thinking to change my `rsync` statement to

```
rsync -abh /path/to/source /path/to/target
```

Will `rsync` now check local source and target files byte by byte or will it use modification time and/or size to determine if the source file needs to be backed up? I definitely do **not** want to rely on file size or modification times to decide if a backup should take place.

**UPDATE**

Notice the `-b` option in the `rsync` instruction. It means that destination files will be backed up before they are replaced. So *blindly* rsync'ing all files in the source folder, e.g., by supplying `--ignore-times` as suggested in the comments, is not an option. It would create too many duplicate files and waste storage space. Keep also in mind that I am trying to reduce backup time and workload on a local machine. Just backing up everything would defeat that purpose.

So my question could be rephrased as, is `rsync` capable of doing a file comparison on a byte by byte basis?

Comment: It will use size and mod time, but you can configure this: `-I, --ignore-times
Normally rsync will skip any files that are already the same size and have the same modification timestamp. This option turns off this lqquick checkrq behavior, causing all files to be updated.` (man rsync)

Comment: @thatotherguy But this would mean that it would even update files that do not differ at all, right? This is also not an option because I do a backup of the files in the destination folder before replacing them - that is what the `-b` option is meant to do. I will update the question to emphasize this behaviour.

Comment: Have you timed a byte by byte comparison against a checksum; I think you'll probably want to avoid the former...

Comment: @l'L'l Thankyou!!

Comment: @l'L'l "Have you timed ..." Yes, in case of two identical 600MB files rsync will finish in about 5 seconds while `cmp`, e.g., will finish the comparison in 2 seconds. This is not surprising since in both cases the entire files have to be read and in the latter case two additional checksums are calculated which has more overhead than simply comparing bytes for equality. Unless, of course, rsync would provide a mechanism to store checksums it once calculated for the destination files. But, AFAIK, rsync does not store file checksums.

Comment: @nautical your use of `cmp` in this way - even if it's to generate a file list to pipe to `rsync` will effectively trade your saved writes for un-necessary reads.  `rsync` at least stops comparing the moment a change is detected, by contrast the overhead to do this using `cmp` would be countered and then some

Comment: @hmedia1 `cmp` will also abort after it encounters the first difference. You are probably confusing `cmp` with `diff`, which will, by default, examine the entire files. However, with the option `diff -q` it will abort after the first difference, too.

Comment: @nautical Try it.  You're drawing  conclusions again.  Please go ahead and make your own sync tool using `cmp`, `bash`, and `cp` if you want.  You will very soon see for reasons I cannot enlighten you to now that you're not about to outrun `rsync` in your desired balance of efficiency and accuracy.   Remember you're the one that asked the question.  I'm happy to provide clarification if I happen to know the answer, but you seem unwavering in the way you demand `rsync` needs to work without actually fully understanding it.  That lack of understanding is evident by the answer you accepted.

Comment: @nautical you say you are trying to reduce workload and backup time.  How is it that you think reading every byte on every file on your drive is going to achieve that ?  Also why do you still want to compare files with the same name, in the same folder location, with the same size and the same modification date ??  If you can reasonably answer those two questions you'll get a meaningful answer very quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do byte-by-byte comparison of files instead of checksum, the way you are expecting it.

The way `rsync` works is to create two processes, sender and receiver, that create a list of files and their metadata to decide with each other, which files need to be updated. This is done even in case of local files, but in this case processes can communicate over a pipe, not over a network socket. After the list of changed files is decided, changes are sent as a delta or as whole files.

Theoretically, one could send whole files in the file list to the other to make a diff, but in practice this would be rather inefficient in many cases. Receiver would need to keep these files in the memory in case it detects the need to update the file, or otherwise the changes in files need to be re-sent. Any of the possible solutions here doesn't sound very efficient.

There is a good overview about (theoretical) mechanics of `rsync`: https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html

Comment: I was really hoping for another answer. I am not an expert when it comes to rsync but I have done some research on the matter at hand a few months ago when I first implemented my script. Now I revisited the issue and was hoping that I overlooked something. I guess I will have to reimplement parts of my script when copying locally. Thanks.

Comment: @ErkiA - The actual first line of your answer is factually incorrect.  Is it possible to do a byte-by-byte comparison.  I explained this clearly.  By specifying `--block-size=1` you are making the block size 1 byte.  This will be very inefficient and take forever.  For example, debugging looks like this for *every byte*: `chunk[3871960] offset=3871960 len=1 sum1=00740074`

Comment: To be honest.  Most of this answer is wrong.  The negotiation criteria for selected files to be synced is one thing.  The other thing is the method in which that is done.

Comment: The summary you linked to is mostly about running `rsync` in **`--daemon`** mode as a listening server.  **This is completely different**.  In any case.

Comment: @hmedia1 As your own debug output shows, this "byte" is actually a chunk. This is hardly the byte-by-byte comparison that the OP is asking about. Also, you are already talking about the file synchronization, but the question is more about which files should rsync include in the backup (or more specifically, which files should be **skipped**)

Comment: @ErkiA A **single byte** chunk, yes.  Hence inefficient.  Exactly what files to skip based on the given non-negotiable criteria, requires understanding of additional concepts.  OP wants to ensure that files of the same name, in the same folder, with the same modification time, and the same size, should **NOT** be criteria for skipping.  But at the same time, OP does **not want to wastefully re-copy files every time**.  See the conflict here ?  The understanding of "byte by byte" basis is not in line with the intent of why it's being asked.  **YES** it's possible.  **NO** it's not efficient.

Comment: @hmedia1 I am honestly struggling to understand which part of my question is throwing you off. I want to do a byte-by-byte comparison in order to determine **if** a backup has to be done. The "byte-by-byte" comparison you are describing would take place **after** this decision has been made when delta transfering the file. What I was looking for is something like `if cmp file1 file2;then do_backup ...`. Alas, rsync does not provide such a mechanism.

Comment: @hmedia1 By default, `rsync` skips files based on modtime and size. OP wants to verify, that the file contents are also the same. `rsync` has `--checksum` flag for this, that calculates checksums of files on **both ends** and skips the file only if these also match. OPs question is, that wouldn't it be more efficient, if `rsync` would compare those files like `diff` does, instead of checksumming, and is there an option for that. The answer is no - there is no such option.

Comment: @nautical - You've cleared it up now.  Unfortunately there is a "literal" answer and a "for all intents and purposes" answer - The problem is that neither one is meaningful until these intents are cleared up, because of the implications in doing so.  I will provide two comments now, one for each answer.

Comment: **Literal**: byte-by-byte comparison **before** selecting **which** files to transfer ?  **YES**, - Sample of this comparison: `match at 25 last_match=25 j=23 len=1 n=0` -- but the **only reason I can think** that you would want this is based on an assumption that this would be more efficient.  In this case, a **whole file checksum** would be **much** more efficient, but that's not what you asked (but it's implied given that you consider checksum too much overhead).  So literally ?  **YES** but I **cannot think of a use (EVER) for it**

Comment: **For all intents and purposes**:  **NO** - but - this is not a limitation of `rsync` - byte-by-byte comparison is clearly misunderstood if there's a view that this would be considered beneficial for any purpose.

Answer (score 6):

> #### Question:  *is rsync capable of doing a file comparison on a byte by byte basis?*

Strictly speaking, Yes:

- It's a **block by block** comparison, but you can change the block size.
- You could use `--block-size=1`, (but it would be **unreasonably** inefficient and inappropriate for basically every)

The block based rolling checksum is the default behavior over a network.

Use the `--no-whole-file` option to force this behavior locally.  (see below)

> **Statement 1.** *Calculating the checksums even introduces a speed down in this case.*

This is why it's off by default for local transfers.

Using the `--checksum` option forces an entire file read, as opposed to the default block-by-block delta-transfer checksum checking

> **Statement 2.** *Will rsync now check local source and target files byte by byte or
>
>          will it use modification time and/or size to determine if the source
>   file        needs to be backed up?*

By default it will use size & modification time.

You can use a combination of `--size-only`, `--(no-)ignore-times`, `--ignore-existing` and
`--checksum` to modify this behavior.

> **Statement 3.** I *definitely **do not** want to rely on file size or modification times* to decide if a        backup should take place.

Then you need to use `--ignore-times` and/or `--checksum`

> **Statement 4.** *supplying **--ignore-times** as suggested in the comments, is **not** an option*

Perhaps using `--no-whole-file` **and** `--ignore-times` is what you want then ?  This forces the use of the delta-transfer algorithm, but for **every** file regardless of timestamp or size.

You would (in my opinion) only ever use this combination of options if it was critical to avoid meaningless writes (though it's critical that it's *specifically* the meaningless writes that you're trying to avoid, **not** the efficiency of the system, since it wouldn't actually be more efficient to do a delta-transfer for local files), **and** had reason to believe that files with identical modification stamps and byte size could indeed be different.

I fail to see how modification stamp and size in bytes is anything but a logical first step in identifying changed files.

If you compared the following two files:

- File 1 (local) :  **File.bin** - `79776451 bytes` and modified on the `15 May 07:51`
- File 2 (remote): **File.bin** - `79776451 bytes` and modified on the `15 May 07:51`

**The default behaviour is to skip these files.**  If you're not satisfied that the files should be skipped, and want them compared, you can **force** a block-by-block comparison and differential update of these files using `--no-whole-file` **and** `--ignore-times`

## So the summary on this point is:

1. Use the default method for the most efficient backup and archive
2. Use `--ignore-times` and `--no-whole-file` to force delta-change (block by block checksum, transferring only differential data) if for some reason this is necessary
3. Use `--checksum` and `--ignore-times` to be completely paranoid and wasteful.

> **Statement 5.** *Notice the **`-b`** option in the rsync instruction. It means that destination files will be backed up before they are replaced*

Yes, but this can work however you want it to, it **doesn't** necessarily mean a **full backup** every time a file is updated, and it **certainly** doesn't mean that a full transfer will take place at all.

You can configure rsync to:

- Keep 1 or more versions of a file
- Configure it with a `--backup-dir` to be a full incremental backup system.

Doing it this way doesn't waste space other than what is required to retain differential data.  I can verify that in practise as there would not be nearly enough space on my backup drives for all of my previous versions to be full copies.

---

## Some Supplementary Information

---

#### Why is Delta-transfer *not* more efficient than copying the whole file locally?

***Because you're not tracking the changes to each of your files.***  If you actually have a delta file, you can merge **just** the changed bytes, but you need to know **what** those changed bytes are first.  **The only way you can know this is by reading the entire file**

For example:

- I modify the first byte of a 10MB file.
- I use `rsync` with delta-transfer to sync this file
- `rsync` immediately sees that the first byte (or byte within the first block) has changed, and proceeds (by default `--inplace`) to change just that block
- **However**, `rsync` doesn't know it was only the first byte that's changed.  It will keep checksumming until the whole file is read

## For all intents and purposes:

- Consider `rsync` a tool that **conditionally** performs a `--checksum` based on whether or not the file timestamp or size has changed.  Overriding this to `--checksum` is essentially equivalent to `--no-whole-file` and `--ignore-times`, since both will:

  - Operate on **every file**, regardless of time and size
  - Read every block of the file to determine which blocks to sync.

**What's the benefit then?**

The whole thing is a tradeoff between **transfer bandwidth**, and **speed / overhead**.

- `--checksum` is a good way to only ever send differences over a network
- `--checksum` while ignoring files with the same timestamp and size is a good way to both only send differences over a network, and also maximize the speed of the entire backup operation

Interestingly, it's probably **much** more efficient to use `--checksum` as a blanket option than it would be to **force** a delta-transfer for **every file**.

Comment: This is nicely formatted and thorough answer, but I don't think it correctly answers the main question - is rsync able to do byte-by-byte comparsion instead of checksum (for performance reasons).

Comment: About the 'not how it works' part: I supplied the `--ignore-times` option and that is exactly what it did. It generated (in a test run) a duplicate for a file that had not changed at all. The folder that I actually backup has thousands of files. In the real case scenario almost every file would have a duplicate, thus half of the required storage for the backup would be wasted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Erki & @nautical.  This is technically an rsync program usage question, I've just tried to add to the knowledge base based on what I could make of the question at the time for the benefit of those that may implement rsync or part of the answer into a solution they are working on.  I will edit my answer to try and more thoroughly address the direct question now that it's been refined.

Comment: @nautical I trust my edited answer will be much more helpful.  I assume your use case is specialised here so I've made no assumptions in trying to address each point.

Comment: @hmedia1 As I understand by [reading this](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html), there are different checksums for the file list and delta transfer. `--checksum` option is for the file list that is generated to detect the files that need to be updated (before delta-transfer). My quick test showed, that using `-a -b --ignore-times --no-whole-file` does create a copy of all files, no matter if they changed or not.

Comment: Overall, this is a good answer, but I can't upvote because (as I see it): 1) saying, that byte-by-byte comparison is possible, but it's actually block-by-block comparison with checksums, is a bit of a stretch (and in the context of the question, it's a wrong answer, because the intention is to avoid checksums and overhead);  2) tests show, that using `-b` and `--ignore-times` without `--checksum` does make a copy of all files (also: `--checksum` is not equivalent to `--no-whole-file` and `--ignore-times` in this case)

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you put into this answer but you are taking single statements of my question out of context and provide solutions that are not suitable. I keep re-reading my question to see if there may be a problematic phrasing. Is it the part with the "delta transfer"? I only mentioned that to emphasize that I am on a local machine and that a delta transfer is pointless in this case. I want to avoid checksum calculation entirely in this case, be it to determine if a file needs backup or later in the process by delta transfering.

Comment: @nautical Here's the thing - you can't compare a file byte by byte without **reading** the file.  The most efficient next best thing is a checksum.  Checksumming an **entire file** is more efficient than checksumming a single byte at a time.  The term "byte-by-byte comparison" has in this way been misunderstood.  Systems that do "byte level" changes require delta files.  There is no system that will ignore modification times, and file size, and then check a file byte-by-byte in a more efficient manner than just overwriting the file.  **this is why rsync is designed the way it is**.

Comment: @nautical you've presented a scenario that is erroneous unfortunately, so I'm offering you an explanation if I can first understand how it is you feel that a file of the same name, in the same folder, with the same modification time, and the same size, should **still** be re-transferred, by using two mutually exclusive methods - one being the delta change, and one being the complete over-write.  In one hand you say checksumming is too inefficient, on the other hand, you say you don't want to re-write every file every time.

Comment: @ErkiA - Sorry, your facts are wrong again on this : "`-a -b --ignore-times --no-whole-file`" <-- How many times did you try it ??  It will only create an **INITIAL** full copy.  After that it will rotate the backup, and **DELTA-TRANSFER** the changes.

Comment: @ErkiA - Configuring the backup regime is a **DIFFERENT** topic.  One I'm happy to elaborate on, but not while the understanding of everything else is still where it is.

Comment: @hmedia1 Several times. And as you say it - it rotates the backup - making copy of **all** the files, because there is effectively no skip criterion. The delta-transfer is irrelevant after that.

Comment: @ErkiA - **INITIALLY** - **DEPENDING** on the configuration of the backup.  Can we discuss backup configuration later and focus on the selection criteria ??  (Even you pointed this out)  -  I've been using `rsync` with incremental backups in the most complex of deployments across differing filesystems and never wasted a byte, syncs are efficient, and I can safely sync over a WAN connection knowing that 2TB of local hard disk isn't about to be re-copied.

Comment: @hmedia1 I don't know, what you exactly mean by "initially", but I have two copies of each file in the destination folder, which is twice as much as actually needed, because no file has actually changed during backups. And depending on configuration, it can only get worse, as I see it.

Comment: @ErkiA guess we *will* talk backups then.   Could please advise then with your test setup, what happens when you modify the file 4 times and run the same sync command 4 times.  **1.** How many bytes are transferred in total, and **2.** how many copies are in your target folder ??

Comment: @hmedia1 When I modify one file 4 times and run the same command after each modification, I have two copies of **all** files in the destination folder - complete waste, because only one of them has changed. Bytes transferred is not relevant in the context of this question.

Comment: @ErkiA and you could run it 44 more times and there'd still only be two copies.  But what does your unconfigured `-b` have to do with whether or not a byte by byte comparison is possible with `rsync`?   Seems the goal posts keep moving in this thread.  Do you folks want a verifiable answer or do you want to keep defending this one?  Because it's not only technically incorrect but it doesn't address, support, or acknowledge the false premise under which the question was asked - it doesn't benefit the community to imply that byte level comparison is better but that `rsync` fails to provide it

Comment: A random DV recently without any explanation yet everything I've stated remains verifiable